# How to optimize memory use for loop in tensorflow?

Tags: for-loop, tensorflow, loss-function

Take Mean Squared Error(MSE) for example.Generally this function is defined as follow:

```
def exp_loss(batch_p, batch_t):
    loss_val = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(batch_p, batch_t))
    return loss_val
```

But when I use for loop to calculate error elementwise, like this:

```
def exp_loss_for(batch_p, batch_t):
    loss_val = 0
    ns = int(batch_p.get_shape()[0])  # batch_size
    sl = int(batch_p.get_shape()[1])  # sequence_length
    nd = int(batch_p.get_shape()[2])  # num_dim
    for i in range(ns):
        for j in range(sl):
            for k in range(nd):
                loss_val += tf.square(tf.subtract(batch_p[i, j, k], batch_t[i, j, k]))
    loss_val = loss_val / (ns * sl * nd)
    return loss_val
```

tensorflow will **consume too much memory** in graph constructing stage.
If I have to custom my own loss function using for-loop like `exp_loss_for` but more complex, is there any way that I can dot to reduce the memory use?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid for loops. Even more complex loss functions can be usually expressed with tensorflow operations without using for loops.